# Why do I get different tabs when adding 'search?q=%2Btitle:' to the Stack Overflow URL?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, homepage

My Stack Overflow bookmark is "https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Btitle:" which adds "+title:" to the search box. Most of my searches are based on searches on titles and the automatic insertion saves me some keystrokes. However the homepage is always the same. The same set of questions starting from the very first question asked in July 2008.

If I omit the query string, I get different tabs. Why?

The purpose of my query string is just to add the text in the search box. It doesn't make sense to me that it also changes the tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's just what happens when you search for a blank title; it matches all posts and sorts from oldest to newest. You can't provide the search parameter when loading a page and not expect it to modify the results; that's the whole point. The fact that it fills in the search box is just a side-effect. If you want to pre-populate the search box without actually performing a search, you should write a userscript that does it